# Can you tell the difference between plane shift and invisibility?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, invisibility

Should/could a creature tell the difference between an enemy gone invisible and an enemy that switched to the ethereal plane? For example when someone uses blink, would an enemy NPC continue attacking the spot where he was, assuming he is invisible?

I'm not sure if there is a RAW answer for this, so I would also appreciate answers based on experience.

Comment: rocks fall (or a Fireball goes off).  1. everybody dies.  2. everybody is on another plane and is unaffected.  That's obviously the *major* difference.

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't doubt that there is a difference, I'm just wondering if you would notice it in the heat of battle.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## 1. Invisible is not hidden

While being invisible does make you able to attempt to hide anywhere, it does not make you automatically undetected. You still make sound for example. (See the sidebar on hiding on page 177 of the PHB.) Thus it is usually clear whether a character disappeared to another plane or not. Circumstances might affect this, so the DM might rule otherwise.

## 2. Recognize the spell

You can attempt to identify the spell as it is being cast. You use your reaction and make an Int(Arcana) check. You can find the rules on page 85 of XGtE.

Comment: Another possible way to tell spells apart is by the components. Some spells will have VSM and other will only have a subset of those

Comment: @Medix2 I always believed this was already included in the arcana check. Would make interesting new question, I guess.

Comment: I always thought that was part of the arcane check too, a layman won't know the components of plane shift Vs invisibility.

Comment: By sounds that a person makes I assume you mean breathing and the sound of his clothes moving? Do you think it would be reasonable to say an enemy has the time and focus to stand and listen for that in the middle of combat?

Comment: @findusl They are already paying attention to that person, as either that person wants to kill them, they want to kill him, or both. 5e practically assumes you are hyper-aware during combat (and mechanics are written with that in mind). But, as I said, if the circumstances warrant it, the DM can overrule this (due to large distances, noisy environment, etc.).

Comment: @findusl you can use your Action to make an active Wisdom(Perception) check, but you always have your Passive Perception available for these as well.

Comment: Noob question: is it possible to loudly yell "plane shift!" while casting invisibility?

Comment: @Medix2 we are not on a forum. If you want this topic addressed, ask it as a question please.

Comment: @Mołot I just find it near-indisputable that you *can* tell if somebody is moving their hand around, or moving their lips, or pulling items out of a pouch that asking it seems... out of place. So I'm asking for you to clarify that; that you believe those things are not intuitively noticed, and thus me asking the question *is* valid

Comment: @Borgh that could be a question by itself.

Comment: @Medix2 The question is not whether you can see them perform the components, it is about knowing the exact components of spells. That is why the check is arcana and not perception.

Comment: @szega If you know they are casting one of two spells, and one spell has VSM and the other only V, you can tell, without a check, which spell they are casting. Not exactly applicable to this case, but in general, you can see *which* components are being used and thus know what the possible spells are

Comment: @Medix2 How would you know those are the two only options? eg. they could have cast *misty step* (V only) and teleported to a place you cannot see at the moment. Thinking it through ("Okay, it was VSM, they seem to have disappeared, and did he just chant vhorblux?") is represented by the reaction you spend.

Comment: @Szega I honestly don't think this is relevant to the question here